# Curious about USB-C D1+, D1-, D2+, D2-

Tags: usb

I have curious about the usb-c d1+, d1-, d2+ and d2-,

If I have two for example atmega328p, does this usb-c can program one of the atmega using d1+-, and program to another atmega using d2+- separately, which means I may program two atmega when I plugged the usb-c with different polarity.

I know all people just connect them together, but I wonder if my idea will works or not? If my idea works, then may I need two usb to uart ICs like ft232RL or not? Or you may have other connections?